# JDeveloper stuck on Generating the business service

Tags: jdeveloper, osb

I am using JDeveloper 12.2.1.2 on Windows to develop applications for OSB.

I had previously used the database adapter in another project within the same application. Now when I drag a DB adapter into the composite, the wizard prompts me for all values, then gets stuck on "Generating the business service..." message without actually adding it. The menu works. I can perform other functions.

I tried closing JDeveloper and restarting, then adding again. Stuck at same point.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Found the problem.

I had created a folder named "Database" under "Resources". In the first step of the wizard, I selected this folder as the location to create the business service in.

I then noticed that the files were getting created in "Resources". Apparently, JDeveloper messes up the location and then gets stuck because it can't find the files it creates in the wrong folder.

The solution is to not make any changes to the default folder location.